# Switch from https back to http

Tags: https, site-url, http

I recently moved my site to https, by installing a SSL-certificate on the server and updating the site address and site home in the wp-admin to use https.

Due to some errors my client is experiencing with https, I would like to switch back. I have edited the values in the wp-admin, to be without http**s**. I have also followed several options described in: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

However, nothing seems to work. I am not sure what is going wrong. It seems that internally Wordpress is redirecting all url's to https, although the site_url is changed.

I have also cleared my .htaccess file, but this also does not seem to be the problem. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: without knowing what exactly is your setup this is too localized to be answered.

Comment: Why not fix the issues with HTTPS instead? HTTPS is all good.

Comment: Could it just be a caching issue at your end? Have you tried elsewhere on other networks to see if the issue happens everywhere? And yes, like @cybmeta I'd suggest it's worth fixing the 'errors' and persisting with https if you can.

Comment: You don't have `FORCE_SSL_LOGIN` or `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` defined in wp-config do you? or [e.g. a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/) that'll do that for you? You can test if it's your server by doing `curl -D - yoursite.com` to see the redirect. AFAIK a redirect generated by WordPress will have no HTML body whereas one generated by Apache will.

Comment: You are right, fixing HTTPS would be great. However, my client is working with some kind of software, that gathers images from their website. HTTPS has broken this software, of which I have no further control.

I did not have FORCE_SSL_LOGIN or FORCE_SSL_ADMIN in my wp-config. I also tested over other networks, so it didn't seem like a caching issue.

When I do curl -D - www.wscvlietland.nl I now get the version without https. So it seems that by some miracle this issue has resolved itself. Thanks for your pointers though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try these:

**1. make sure the values changed in database**

If you can't login to wp-admin > settings to confirm that, you can go to database, wp_options table and look for `siteurl` and `home` values

**2. add code to wp-config.php**

Add these lines to wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

**3. Clear your cache**

Make sure that you clear the cache from any cache plugins you're using and also from your browser

Also try adding this to `wp-config.php` (note "false")

```
define( 'WP_CACHE', false );
```

**4. check https / ssl related plugins**

You might be using any plugin which is causing this, like ssl insecure content fixer, etc.

**5. Cloudflare or other dns side redirect**

Make sure that the site isn't using any dns based redirect

**6. disable all plugins and confirm**

**7. change theme to default and check**

Comment: Thanks, tried all these steps earlier and apparently one of them worked. It appeared that there is some sort of cache on the Wordpress get_option table. I tried to circumvent it in the code, with no result. But apparently this cache is refreshed now, as the domain is working correctly.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped. Please mark the answer as correct if it was :)